# Angular JS : how to access data from the directives controller in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and not able to solve the following problem :  I am able to print the value of the followup questions in the console but not able to print them on the webpage i.e., I am not able to access the scope variables of the app directive function (i.e. followup()) in the HTML. Here is my plunker link. Can anyone help me out?

```
`https://plnkr.co/edit/sBwXyd7jwsQFZRfiMkZ9`
```